# Calculating Average in SAP HANA CV for duplicated rows

Tags: sql, hana

```
  ColumnA   ColumnB  ColumnC  
     A         10       xyz     
     A         10       def     
     A         10       mno     
     B         20       pqr     
     B         20       abc     
     C         50       uvw
```

I have a data where we are getting duplicate values due to ColumnC
I need to calculate total average as :

`(10+20+50)/3`(i.e. unique count of ColumnA)

Currently I tried to make a counter on ColumnA as CA_Count:

avg= ColumnA/CA_Count;
but it is working as:

```
(10+10+10+20+20+50)/3
```

It is Compulsary to keep ColumnC in output!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery like this:

```
select avg(columnB)
from (select distinct columnA, columnB from t) t;
```

However, your data structure is suspicious because you shouldn't be repeating values on multiple rows.  You should have a table where `columnA` and `columnB` are unique.